# Entity Framework fails to update SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a problem with a constraint in my database. A `StairWay` class uses a strongly typed property called `Tread`. I receive a message that the constraint does not exist when I try to `update-database` but the code below tells me it is created. I am using Entity Framework, SQL Server with ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Screenshot of the error message:

[image]

```
//Classes I have created  
public class StairWay
{
        public StairTread Tread { get; set; }
        public int StairTreadId { get; set; }
        public int StairWayId { get; set; }
}

public class StairTread
{
        public int StairTreadId { get; set; }
        public int StairWayId { get; set; }
}

// SQL code generated
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StairTread]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_StairTread_StairCases_StairWayId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([StairWayId]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[StairWays] ([StairWayId]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: SQL ALTER statement shows FK to StairWay . But your model shows FK to StairTread. Is it 1:1 relation?

Comment: @sam yes, it is a 1:1 relation.

Comment: Have the FK relationship on StairTread side in your model too. Remove `public StairTread Tread { get; set; }` from StairWay class and add `[ForeignKey("StairWayId")]public virtual StairWay Way { get; set; }` to StairTread  class to match database FK (as shown in your ALTER statement).

Comment: @sam I need to keep the Tread property in StairWays.cs.

Comment: then decorate `public StairTread Tread { get; set; }` with Foreign Key and re-run all the migrations (make sure you completely do it from scratch). At the end, we are looking for something that shows model and DB in sync.

Comment: Also,before running migrations, pleaes delete `public int StairWayId { get; set; }' from StairTread as well.

Comment: Thanks @sam, Now I receive an error that I dont have permission to drop a constraint or the constraint does not exist. Frankly I gave up on EF. this code was a test project, I've decided to use Dapper instead. At least I know what causes an issue with dapper.